# TopMenu Applet does not work on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mate, applet, globalmenu

I have installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and I installed `mate-applet-topmenu`. Then I added the applet to my panel. A separator appeared but it did not show global menu.

I also tried to install libtopmenu server and client for gtk 2 and 3 but nothing changed.

Please help me to bring global menu to my MATE desktop.